# jQuery: Uncaught TypeError: .find is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape prices of amazon search results using jQuery, but I keep getting this error "Uncaught TypeError: results[i].find is not a function".

scrape.js

```
/// example: user searched 'keyboards' on amazon

//grab search result rows from amazon search result page
var results = $('.s-main-slot.s-result-list.s-search-results.sg-row').children;

console.log(results) //htmlCollection(30)[divRow1, divRow2,...,divRow30]

//loop through table results and find child element for price
for (var i=0; i<results.length; i++){
    let r = results[i].find('a-price'); //<--- error
    console.log(r);
};
```

I've also tried:

```
//grab search result rows from amazon search result page
var results = $('.s-main-slot.s-result-list.s-search-results.sg-row').children; 

console.log(results) //htmlCollection(30)[divRow1, divRow2,...,divRow30]

//loop through table results and find child element for price
for (var i=0; i<results.length; i++){
    let r = $(results[i]).find('a-price'); //<--- error
    console.log(r);
};
```

and this.

```
//grab search result rows from amazon search result page
var results = $('.s-main-slot.s-result-list.s-search-results.sg-row').children;

console.log(results) //htmlCollection(30)[divRow1, divRow2,...,divRow30]

//loop through table results and find child element for price
for (var i=0; i<results.length; i++){
    let r = $(this).find('a-price'); //<--- error
    console.log(r);
};
```

Same error: .find is not a function. I think the bug is that i'm referencing a DOM object and not a jQuery object, but I can't seem to figure out how to fix that.

Comment: `$(selector).children` is a function in jQuery

Comment: `.children` is a _function_ on jQuery objects and jQuery never produces an `HTMLCollection`, unless you’re accessing the DOM API directly. Are you sure `$` is jQuery and not a [Web Console helper](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Helpers)? Even if `results` was a jQuery object of elements, `results[i]` would still be a DOM element. You’d have to use [`.eq`](//api.jquery.com/eq/) instead.

Comment: What are you scraping with? Node.js? Userscript? Something else? How are you attempting to load jQuery there?

Comment: Ahh I see my mistake. I was using it from the chrome console, so it was referencing the web console helper. 

I'm trying to make a chrome extension that scrapes with jQuery. So I load jQuery by storing it in my extension project folder and importing it in the my code. The extension injects a file 'content.js' (it contains the code of scrape.js above) into the amazon tab, and sends data back to the extension. I thought I could scrape the data by manipulating the DOM but I'm realizing that jQuery might not be getting injected.

Comment: I originally wanted to use something like node/ selenium to scrape, but it's tricky with chrome extensions. I have a working version which uses Python/BeautifulSoup/Selenium, but I need it to run on the client side and interface through a browser extension.